# Using Stored Procedures in php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Im using mysql stored procedures in my databases and now I want to be able to use it with my php code but none of the examples I've searched show a clear way to do this. Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<?php include("navbar.php")?>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

    mysqli_query($link, "CALL AddUser($firstname, $lastname)");
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    First Name:<input type="text" name="firstname" required>
    Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastname" required>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddUser`(IN in_first_name VARCHAR(100), IN in_last_name VARCHAR(100) )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `users`(first_name, last_name) VALUES (in_first_name, in_last_name );
END
```

Here is the table in the database `test`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `users_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`users_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `users`

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`users_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Joey', 'Rivera'),
(2, 'John', 'Doe'),
(3, 'Cesar', 'Guerrero'),
(4, 'Maribel', 'Guerrero'),
(8, 'Marc', 'Jacobs');
```

Comment: as peterm touches upon when suggesting you use prepared statements, your code is open to SQL injection attacks as you are inserting user supplied (POST) data directly into SQL statements.

Comment: as far as your question... there's nothing special about doing anything with SQL in PHP. YOu just have to give valid SQL to the server. Try printing out your SQL text before executing it, and see what it is. Try pasting that into command line mySQL monitor or PHPMyAdmin and see what happens.

Comment: I am aware this is, I just need this to work before I start adding security to my code @JAL

Comment: can you post SHOW CREATE TABLE users?

Comment: it will be added to the post take a look @JAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u should have to name attribute for submit button..i hope this will help.

```
 <input type="submit" name='submit' value="submit">
```

Comment: the data still didn't go through

Comment: can u check by this?  mysqli_query($link, "CALL AddUser(".$firstname.", ".$lastname.")");

Comment: mysqli_query($link, "CALL AddUser('".$firstname."','".$lastname."')");

Comment: Thanks for reminding me as well. Definitely worth it.

Answer (score 3):

String literals should be quoted. Try to change

```
mysqli_query($link, "CALL AddUser($firstname, $lastname)");
```

to

```
mysqli_query($link, "CALL AddUser('$firstname', '$lastname')");
                                  ^          ^  ^         ^
```

and add at least some the basic error handling

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
if (!$mysqli_query("CALL AddUser('$firstname', '$lastname')")) {
    echo "CALL failed: " . $mysqli_errno($link) . " - " . $mysqli_error($link);
    exit();
}
```

**On a side note:** consider to learn and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) intend of interpolating query strings.

---

A version of your code using prepared statements might look like

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

    $link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die('Connect failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); //TODO: a better error handling
    }
    $stmt = $link->prepare("CALL AddUser(?, ?)");
    if (!$stmt) {
        die('Prepare failed: ' . $link->error); //TODO: a better error handling
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $firstname, $lastname);
    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        die('Execute failed: ' . $link->error); //TODO: a better error handling
    }
}
?>
```

And as @MayurKukadiya mentioned add `name` attribute  to your input

```
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="submit">
```

Comment: add some basic error handling as suggested in the updated answer run it again and post the exact error message. And show the definition of your stored procedure.

Comment: even this didn't work for me and it didn't give me any error messages and my procedure is above now.

Answer (score -1):

PDO is your need, make sure you have pdo-mysql extention enabled and installed

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_returns_string(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000); 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();

print "procedure returned $return_value\n";
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php